# How can I change the port for localhost in PHP (Apache, Xampp)?

Tags: php, apache, xampp, localhost, port

I updated my version of PHP (by installing a newer version of XAMPP), but I'm having trouble getting the server to use the necessary port with PHP so that it will run the correct version of PHP.

Due to the well-documented conflicts for machines running Windows, I changed the Apache ports to 81 (from 80) in the httpd.conf file for: `Listen` and `ServerName localhost`.

It appears to be running correctly. Both Apache and MySQL are running in the XAMPP Control Panel

> Apache - Port: 81, 443 
>   MySQL - Port: 3306

PHP ini was set to 3306, and I therefore left it as is.

`http://localhost:81` shows that I'm running the correct version of PHP *(Version 5.6.3)*., however when I try opening a file at `localhost:81` I receive the following error message:

> Object not found! The requested URL was not found on this server. If
>   you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
>   If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster. 
>   Error 404 localhost Apache/2.4.10 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1i PHP/5.6.3

The only way it's allowing me to access the files is at *http://localhost:2556*, which is running an old version of PHP.

Any suggestions how I can get my PHP documents to access the proper port and version of PHP?

Comment: That sounds like you did not set up your VirtualHost correctly or something …

Comment: @CBroe - The instructions don't seem to require that but I figured I'd give it a shot ;-) Unfortunately that seems to be causing some other problems, which I believe might be due to my scenario being slightly different than the ones outlined in the instructions I've found for changing the VirtualHost. Any chance you can help point me in the right direction?